# why bundle install rails 0.9.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

In my Gemfile I have:

gem 'rails'

until yesterday it works well, my rails version was 3.2.9.
I've added no new gems and today, after running bundle update I see that it installs rails-0.9.5.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Running `bundle update` without specifying a gem to update is a bad idea if you haven't set the minor version in your Gemfile. The reason for this is because you will likely upgrade a gem that has a different public interface and it will break your application.

I'd recommend specifying the major and minor version of Rails in your Gemfile so that it "locks" it down so it will only upgrade the patch level:

```
gem "rails", "~> 3.2.9"
```

Then when you want to upgrade it, just run:

```
bundle update rails
```

This will update Rails to the latest patch (3.2.x) and as long as they are following [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), you won't have to worry about it breaking your app.

Comment: Yes I know that only bundle update will break my application, but I don't know why bundle is installing rails-0.9.5 and not the latest rails version.